# How to query through the date range by JIRA REST API?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jql

I want to query issue through the date range, for example:

```
created >= 2016-04-03 and created <= 2016-04-30
```

How can I achieve this using Get or Post ?

Get like this:

```
rest/api/2/search?jql=project=test &created...
```

Post like this:

```
{'jql':'project = test','startAt':0,'maxResults':10,...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for all the people who answer the questions. 
To solve this problem need to pay attention to the following:

1. in jql statement should use 'AND' instead of '&' (You can verify in JIRA's Issue Search screen whether your JQL is correct.)
2. before jql parameters submitted  in the url, we can use  "java.net.URLEncoder.encode() " for  encoding jql.
   For example, I am using HttpClient submitted a request, I want to query by date range:

   ```
   String jql = "assignee = youwei.yao AND status = CLOSED AND created > = 2016-04-03 AND created < = 2016-04-03 order by created"; 
   jql = URLEncoder. Encode (jql, "utf-8"); 
   String url = "http://host:port/rest/api/2/search?jql=" + jql;
   ```

Then submit your request using this url by HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing you're missing is putting `+` where spaces are. E.g. `+and+`.
This works for the GET request.

```
/rest/api/2/search?jql%3Dproject%3Dtest%2Band%2Bcreated%3E%3D2016-04-03%2Band%2Bcreated%3C%3D2016-04-30
```

There is some documentation on how to do it for GET and POST requests in the [latest JIRA REST documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/search)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the url ,"/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=test+and+created>=2016-04-03+and+created<=2016-04-30", post(get) by HttpClient has an error ,the url is illegal.i think it may caused by the '>=',in the JIRA REST API ,i can't find a example meet my requirements

Comment: Ahh, URL encoding it as the other answer suggests would make it work. My browser clearly isn't strict about it and just accepted it when I tried it!

Comment: Unnecessary downvote, see comment above... Edited answer for correctness

Answer (score 0):

For GET:

- Instead of '&' use 'AND'. You can verify in JIRA's [Issue Search](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/advanced-searching-179442050.html) screen whether your JQL is correct.
- You have to URL encode your query parameter. If you're trying things out manually then you can use a website like [this one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) to do that. So you're complete URL will become:

  http://myjira.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project%20%3D%20TEST%20AND%20created%20%3E%3D%202016-04-03%20AND%20created%20%3C%3D%202016-04-30

Comment: thanks very much for your answer. My problem has been solved, just like you said, is the URL coding problem.